# Why I don't see Logs in Firebase Crash Reporting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using `Firebase Crash Reporting`.

I saw [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuLjyFGAABE&feature=youtu.be&t=813) feature which is called `Logs`.

But how to use this?

I've `Google Analytics` in my project, and I'm trying to log crashes using `FirebaseCrash.log()` exactly in the same method.

```
public void sendGoogleAnalyticsEvent(String category, String label, String action) {
    Map<String, String> build = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(category)
            .setLabel(label)
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
    tracker.send(build);
    FirebaseCrash.log("Category: " + category + " label: " + label + " action: " + action);
}
```

But I don't see any `Logs` in the crash. This guy speak about automatically logged events, I don't see this too.
What is wrong ?
[image]

**UPDATE**:
If I select 'Analytics' from the Firebase menu, there everything is shown and works correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Firebase Crash Reporting SDK, currently `10.0.1`

The log that will appear in Firebase Crash Reporting is imported from Firebase Analytics, so you have to use Firebase Analytics instead. [source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7198453)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

For example:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "button");
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("button_click", bundle);

throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
```

the result is shown in this screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

"To report caught exceptions, use report(Throwable).

To attach log messages to a crash report, use log(String) or logcat(int, String, String) at points during execution that will best help you know what happened prior to the crash."

```
// THIS IS ADDITIONAL INFORMATION SHOWN IN LOGS SECTION OF EACH ISSUE
FirebaseCrash.log("User selects Settings");
...

FirebaseCrash.log("User selects Enable BT");
...
```

In your caught exception handler:

```
// THIS SHOWS UP IN ISSUES IN CRASH REPORTING
Throwable t=new Throwable("BluetoothAdapter is null in init_BT()").fillInStackTrace();
FirebaseCrash.report(t);
```

Additionally, events logged with Firebase Analytics logEvent() on the user earlier will also show up in "Logs" for the issue as shown in the answer by Wilik.

Further analysis of crashes (from the Captech link below): 
"When a Crash Report is generated it is created with the "app_exception" event. This event can be used as a condition when creating an Audience in the Analytics dashboard..." [haven´t tried this myself yet]

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/crash/FirebaseCrash
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/an-introduction-to-firebase-analytics-and-crash-reporting